# Validating Referer in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

My organization is testing my laravel app with IBM AppScan and it reveled the following issue. I'm not sure the best way I should be verifying the referer. Details of the scan

```
The following changes were applied to the original request:
- Set header to 'http://bogus.referer.ibm.com'
Reasoning:
The test result seems to indicate a vulnerability because the Test
Response is identical to the Original Response, indicating that the 
Cross-Site Request Forgery attempt was successful, even
though it included a fictive 'Referer' header.  

Request/Response:
GET /data/1?page=3 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Win32) Referer:  
http://bogus.referer.ibm.com
Host: xxxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Accept: text/html,application/
```

Answer (score 2):

Laravel relies on [CSRF token](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/csrf) to prevent the application from CSRF. Validating the header only adds an extra layer of security, however, this can be forged.